# How to use unnest argument in "EXECUTE format()" in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Im trying to send an array inside a "unnest" but using it in an a "EXECUTE format()" , how can i do that?

Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_xvx(
    row_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    open FLOAT(36),
    high FLOAT(36),
    low FLOAT(36),
    close FLOAT(36),
    volume FLOAT(36),
    capital FLOAT(36),
    transactions FLOAT(36)
)
```

Type

```
CREATE TYPE type_ohlcvct AS(
type_open float,
type_high float,
type_low float,
type_close float,
type_volume float,
type_capital float,
type_transactions float
);
```

Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_data_ohlcvct(table_name_ varchar(70) , data_list type_ohlcvct[]) 
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    error_message varchar;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
        'INSERT INTO %I(open,high,low,close,volume,capital,transactions)
        SELECT * FROM unnest(%s)',table_name_ , data_list); 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Ways to call

```
SELECT insert_data_ohlcvct('table_xvx' ,'{"(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)","(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)"}'::type_ohlcvct[]);
SELECT insert_data_ohlcvct('table_xvx' , (ARRAY['(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)','(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)'])::type_ohlcvct[]);
SELECT insert_data_ohlcvct('table_xvx' , ARRAY['(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)'::type_ohlcvct,'(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)']);
```

The error is always the same

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 2:   SELECT * FROM unnest({"(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)","(10,10,10,...
                               ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO table_xvx(open,high,low,close,volume,capital,transactions)
        SELECT * FROM unnest({"(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)","(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)"})
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_data_ohlcvct(character varying,type_ohlcvct[]) line 5 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass parameters to dynamic SQL as strings - pass them as parameters:

```
EXECUTE format(
    'INSERT INTO %I(open,high,low,close,volume,capital,transactions)
    SELECT * FROM unnest($1)',table_name_)
USING data_list;  --<< passes the value to the $1 placeholder
```